# POLYMER: Nesting paper-input under paper-item disables spacebar

Tags: javascript, input, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have run into a bizarre issue with polymer. When nesting a `paper-input` element underneath a `paper-item` element, the `paper-input` will not register the spacebar.

Example:

```
<template>
    <paper-item class="to-do-item">
        <paper-checkbox active="{{done}}"></paper-checkbox>
        <paper-input id="test1" value="Test1"></paper-input>
    </paper-item>
    <paper-input id="test2" value="Test2"></paper-input>
</template>
```

In this example, both `test1` and `test2` will take input, but I can not enter spaces in `test1` whereas I can enter spaces in `test2`. If I copy and paste a space character, it works in either input. Bizarre. Anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: The issue is consistent across devices and browsers, desktop and mobile.

Comment: You can check github for any existing issues: https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues. If you don't find it then create a jsbin or something and you can post an issue there.

Comment: The issue is pending at https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues/28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [github development issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues/28#issuecomment-150166946), the problem is that polymer is interpreting the space as a button click, rather than as an input. The issue is being worked on, but in the interim, commenting out the IronButtonState behavior is a feasible work around.

```
behaviors: [
  Polymer.IronControlState/*,
  Polymer.IronButtonState*/
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The paper-item element implement two  behaviours:

1. Polymer.IronControlState
2. Polymer.IronButtonState

   that I think make the spacebar touch event not available, you can replace the paper-item by the iron-item element if you want.

Comment: There is no iron-item.

Comment: Sorry I meant iron-list, in fact paper-item is  is a non-interactive list item as said in the documentation, if you want to use a list container for laying out your paper elements, use an iron-list

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround available which is described here:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-item/issues/103

The idea of user SPessall is to replace the implementation of polymer-item's _spaceKeyDownHandler() function with an empty function, which can easily be done by this code:

```
ready: function(){
  this.$$('paper-item')._spaceKeyDownHandler = function () {};
}
```